# Identify whether my string contains any hex code or not in java

Tags: java, regex, security, hex

I want to identify whether my string contains any hex code or not.

Use cases

```
String input1 = "hello check this input ";
String input2 = "hello check 0x740x680x690x73 input";
String input3 = "0x680x650x6c0x6c0x6f0x200x630x680x650x630x6b0x200x740x680x690x730x200x690x6e0x700x750x74";
```

> isContainHex(input1) should return false
>
> isContainHex(input2) should return true
>
> isContainHex(input3) should return true

I have tried

```
    String input2 = "hello check 0x740x680x690x73 input";

    if(input2.contains("0x") || input2.contains("\\x"))
    {
        System.out.println("string contains hex");
    }
```

and I am able to find hex but,
If My input contains hex like

```
String input4 = "h68h65h6ch6ch6f check this input ";
```

Here I cant check `input4.contains("h")`

Any one have solution for this?

is there any standard library by which I can achive same?

**Update**

I have wrote following code, and its working well but taking time.

Now can it be optimize

```
try
{
    if (input != null && input.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        String originalHex = null;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        String inputArray[] = null;
        if (StringUtils.countMatches(input, "\\x") > 3)
        {
            originalHex = input.substring(input.indexOf("\\x"), input.lastIndexOf("\\x", input.length()) + 4);
            inputArray = input.split("\\Q\\x\\E");
        }
        else if (StringUtils.countMatches(input, "0x") > 3)
        {
            originalHex = input.substring(input.indexOf("0x"), input.lastIndexOf("0x", input.length()) + 4);
            inputArray = input.split("0x");
        }

        if (inputArray != null && inputArray.length > 0)
        {
            for (String str: inputArray)
            {
                int strLength = str.trim().length();
                if (strLength == 2)
                {
                    output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
                }
                else if (strLength > 2)
                {
                    if (strLength % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        strLength = strLength - 1;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i += 2) 
                    {
                        String val = str.substring(i, i+2);
                        if (val.matches("\\d+"))
                        {
                            output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(val, 16));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            input = input.replaceAll("\\Q" + originalHex + "\\E", output.toString());
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
syso(input);
```

Comment: Could you check the length of the string?  Im assuming it will start with "h" and be longer than a normal word.  Kinda hacky though

Comment: Unrelated: a better name would be "containsHexValues()" or something alike. isContainHex() is simply wrong from a grammar point of view.

Comment: You could use a regex: `boolean containsHex = input.matches(".*(\\x|0x|h)[0-9a-f]+.*);`?

Comment: Beyond that: your problem is ... you are not clear on your **requirements**. It rather looks like "anything coming in" should be be "hex". Since "h68h..." really doesn't look like "hex values". In other words: in order to get anything useful done, you have to first **define** crisp, clear, non-ambiguous rules that tell you what makes up "hex". Your current examples do not.

Comment: Although this won't always work - for example: `I had an idea` - is `had` a hex number or a word?

Comment: @assylias You are pretty much underlining my point. as "hc" would result as "hex" to you. But what about hC? or HC?

Comment: @ghostcat 0x and \x and h are the delimiter can used for hex, So h68 is valid hex value

Comment: So, you are saying that "hig**hc**lass" contains a hex value?

Comment: No, there are two char in hex and `h` is delimiter so hc is not hex and even `hcl` is not hex... Because hex contain 0-9 and a-f chars only

Comment: Yes, but as stated above, " I *had* an idea " is considered as an hex. Should it be considered as such ?

Comment: No, it should not... It's false alarm... But as I can check there is no ASCII representation for had :-(